# Рекурсивный перебор массива объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, рекурсия

Дан массив объектов:

```
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1000,
    name: "Like",
    parent_id: 1003,
    parent_name: "Root"
  },
  {
    id: 1001,
    name: "Count",
    parent_id: 1000,
    parent_name: "Like"
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    name: "Subscribe",
    parent_id: "",
    parent_name: ""
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    name: "Root",
    parent_id: "",
    parent_name: ""
  }
];
```

Задача - преобразовать его в следующий вид:

```
track = {
    1000: '/ > Root>Like',
    1001: '/ > Root>Like > Count',
    1002: '/ > Subscribe',
    1003: '/ > Root'
}
```

Суть функции - преобразовать массив в объект, в котором ключами будут значения id из объектов массива, а значениями этих ключей будут пути, формирующиеся по принципу: если в ключе parent_id пустая строка - возвращается имя данного объекта, это, стало быть базовый случай в рекурсивной функции, но если в parent_id есть значение, то возвращается значение name и происходит поиск объекта у которого значение id равно значению parent_id данного объекта и возвращается его name тоже и т.д.

Базовый случай понятно как прописать:

```
for(let i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].parent_id == "") {
        ans[arr[i].id] = '/ ' + arr[i].name
    }
  }
```

Но вот рекурсивно "пробегать" все объекты не получается реализовать.

Comment: Задача - преобразовать его в следующий вид: и результат не рекурсивного кода который тут присутствует не совпадают так какой еффект нужен взять только те у которых нет parent_id или что + в снимке > это типо внутри есть другой обект а внутри еше один?

Comment: и про рекурсию он эффективен тем что за несколько строчек кода можно пробежатся по очень очень глубоко вложенным обектам как в матрешке но тут зачем к нему прибегать?

Comment: не дискуссии ради.. я не сильно искушен в js, но посчитал наиболее эффективным применение рекурсии поскольку необходимо повторять однотипные действия с массивом.

Comment: нужно сформировать "путь" который состоит из значений name у объектов id которых равен parent_id. если кратко, то собрать путь по принципу адресной строки в диспетчере файлов

Comment: напиши функцию которая принимает массив и делает эту однотипную операцию без рекурсии
ну или если нужна именно рекурися кинь код каторый делает то что тебе нужно без рекурсии а я переведу

Comment: @Armen   ```let ans = {}
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (arr[i].parent_id == "") {
      ans[arr[i].id] = '/> ' + arr[i].name
    } else {
      for (let a in arr) {
        if (arr[a].id == arr[i].parent_id) {
          ans[arr[i].id] = '/> ' + arr[a].name + " > " + arr[i].name
        }
        if (arr[a].parent_id != "") {
         for(let b in arr) {
           if(arr[a].id == arr[i].parent_id) {
             ans[arr[i].id] = '/> ' + arr[b].name + " > " + arr[a].name + " > " + arr[i].name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

console.log(ans)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1000,
    name: "Like",
    parent_id: 1003,
    parent_name: "Root"
  },
  {
    id: 1001,
    name: "Count",
    parent_id: 1000,
    parent_name: "Like"
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    name: "Subscribe",
    parent_id: "",
    parent_name: ""
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    name: "Root",
    parent_id: "",
    parent_name: ""
  }
];

//метод для рекурсивного обхода массива
function recursion(parent_id, arResult = []) {
  for (let item of arr) {
    //если переданный parent_id равен id в массиве
    if (item.id === parent_id) {
      //добавляем имя родителя в начало массива
      arResult.unshift(item.name);
      //если в этой итерации есть parent, то идём получаеть его имя
      if (!!item.parent_id) {
        recursion(item.parent_id, arResult);
      }
      continue;
    }
  }
  //массив превращаем в строку с делителем '>'
  return `${arResult.join(">")} > `;
}

let objResult = {}, parentName = "";

for (let item of arr) {
   //parentName всегда пустой на новой итерации
  parentName = '';
  //если parent_id заполнен
  if (!!item.parent_id) {
    //если у элемента в итерации есть parent, то идём получаеть его имя
    parentName = recursion(item.parent_id, []);
  }
  //собираем результат
  objResult[item.id] = `/ > ${parentName}${item.name}`;
}

console.log(objResult);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но в результате получаем массив объектов, а нужен объект. и на мой неискушенный взгляд Ваше решение тяжело воспринимаемо. но в любом случае, спасибо за внимание

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @Dark_Sky ещё оптимизирую. Чутка ждите, зарефачу код.

Answer (score 0):

получилось так

```
const abra = (arr) => {
  let ans = {}
  const way = '>'
  let el
  const catabra = (inner) => {
    if(typeof inner === 'object'){
      el = arr.find(el => inner.parent_id === el.id)
      return el?.parent_name ? 
      '/' + catabra(el.parent_name) + catabra(inner.parent_name) + catabra(inner.name) :
            inner.parent_name ? 
      '/' + catabra(inner.parent_name) + catabra(inner.name) :
      '/' +  catabra(inner.name)
    }
    return way + inner
  }
  arr.forEach((elem) => {
      ans[elem.id] = catabra(elem)  
  })
  return ans
```

}